Activate/deactivate filtering in django based on condition
I have a bool and if it is True, I want to filter in my query by some stuff, if not I don't want to filter.
At the moment my solution is this:
if my_boolean:
    objects = Class.objects.filter(argument=valuexyz, ...)
else:
    objects = Class.objects.filter(...)

My real query is much longer. I just used this for simplification. Now my questions is could I do this inline?
Like:
objects = Class.objects.filter( if my_boolean: argument=valuexyz; else: no_filtering)`

Is there a way to do it like this somehow? This would save me quite some redundant lines of code.

You can use keyword argument unpacking, or Q objects, but honestly your current method is fast and readable, if there is only one boolean and only 2 possible queries. I would leave it as it is.

@Selcuk I just wondered because my query is much longer and only this one filter is the difference. So It always seems like I have redundant code for nothing. How does keyword argument unpacking work?

Your current method is fast and readable, given that there is only one boolean and only 2 possible queries. I would leave it as it is. That being said, if your actual use case is more complex, you can use:

Keyword argument unpacking using the ** operator with a dict:

my_filter = {
  "field1": "foo"
  "field2__gt": 10
}
if my_boolean:
    my_filter["additional_field"] = "bar"
objects = MyModel.objects.filter(**my_filter)


Q objects:

my_q = Q(field1="foo", field2__gt=10)
if my_boolean:
    my_q &= Q(additional_field="bar")
objects = MyModel.objects.filter(my_q)


Does this work if my_filter is empty?

Yes, you can leave it empty, or it can contain some default filters.

You can work with a Q object to get to similar syntax, like:
from django.db.models import Q

objects = Class.objects.filter(Q(('field__lookup', value) if condition else ()))
although it thus does some wrapping. Perhaps a better way is just make a small helper function:
def qif(*args, _if=True, **kwargs):
    if _condition:
        return Q(*args, **kwargs)
    return Q()
and use:
objects = Class.objects.filter(qif(field__lookup=value, _if=condition))


Note: It might be worth to take a look at django-filter [GitHub] to do filtering based on a QueryDict in a more declarative way.


This is awesome too! Thank you for sharing this solution. Great helper function!
